# Flask-celery broker failover issue

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a flask(0.10.1) app running and configured celery(3.1.25) along with it in the following way

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery
broker_urls = [
    'amqp://my_user:passwd@rabbit-host-1:5672//',
    'amqp://my_user:passwd@rabbit-host-2:5672//',
    'amqp://my_user:passwd@rabbit-host-3:5672//',
]
celery = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_urls)
celery.conf.BROKER_FAILOVER_STRATEGY = "round-robin"

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**app.py**

```
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("testapp")
http_server = WSGIServer(('',8000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

**urls.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

api = Blueprint('api',__name__)

@api.route("/")
def index_api():
    add(10,20)
```

I run the application as `python app.py`,
When I run the flask application if `rabbit-host-1` is down it is picking up the next live broker
`rabbit-host-2` and working fine. But if `rabbit-host-1` is down after I started my app I think it is still connected to `rabbit-host-1` and things are not working even `rabbit-host-2` and `rabbit-host-3` are alive.

But the celery worker was able to failover immediately when any of the brokers are down, by using given `round-robin` fashion.

`celery worker --app=tasks`

Have I missed something to configure properly which is causing failover not to work with flask?

Comment: and python 2.7, please let me know if I am missing something?